# heightForRowAtIndexPath being called too early

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, twitter, height, cells

I'm currently getting Twitter feed via Json and heightForRowAtIndexPath is being called before I can get the length of the tweet. So fullTweet.length is always zero when heightForRowAtIndexPath loads. I'm trying to resize the cells like this http://gyazo.com/632d09685268e1737d3c58bf1718cbff.png so I'm not wasting any extra blank spaces.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(fullTweet.length >= 50) {
  return 50.0f;
      } else
  return 92.0f;
}
```

How my method works

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
cell.textLabel.text = text;
fullTweet = text;
NSLog(@"%i", fullTweet.length);
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;

return cell;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you try to pass the cell's text from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to `heightForRowAtIndexPath` using an instance variable `fullTweet`.

That cannot work, because `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called for *all cells* first, and then 
 `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called for the *visible cells*.

So `heightForRowAtIndexPath` should get the information from the *data source* instead,
something like:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
    if ([text length] <= 50) {
        return 50.0f;
    } else {
        return 92.0f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the data, just call [`reloadData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) on your `UITableView`. This will force the table view to reload all cells.